# Get debug informations from docker container which runs a tomcat server

Tags: spring, debugging, tomcat, intellij-idea, docker

First of all, sorry for my english :-)

Second, I want to run and debug my Spring application in a docker container. The container with the application starts up without any problem, I can reach the app from a browser.

I'm developing it in IntelliJ IDEA on Linux Mint and I would like to retrieve the debug informations from my container. But when I started the app in debug mode the IDEA tells me:

> Cannot retrieve debug connection: java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: unix

Here's my Dockerfile:

```
FROM tomcat:8-jre8

RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y \
    curl \
    vim
RUN rm -rfd /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT
RUN mkdir -p /usr/local/tomcat/conf/Catalina/localhost
RUN echo "<Context docBase=\"/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT\" path=\"\" reloadable=\"true\" />" >> /usr/local/tomcat/conf/Catalina/localhost/ROOT.xml

ENV JPDA_ADDRESS=8000
ENV JPDA_TRANSPORT=dt_socket
ENV JAVA_OPTS=-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=8000,suspend=n,server=y

EXPOSE 8000 8080
```

In the run configurations the port bindigs are correct, the app deploys successfully. Could someone help me? :-)

Comment: Hi. Did you solve it?

Comment: what is you debug run config? and what do you expect to happen on debug?

Comment: Can you try with JAVA_OPTS=
-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=8000 instead ?